# Can access amaraja batteries historical pricess using quantmod package

Tags: r, yahoo-finance, quandl

I have been using the following to access the historical prices of Amraja Batteries. But from today only for this share yahoo finance stopped furnishing values.

getSymbols('AMARAJABAT.NS', src = "yahoo", from = "2022-06-01", to = Sys.Date()+1, auto.assign = FALSE)

I know in Aug the company renamed itself as well as its ticker symbol. The new ticker symbol is giving data but it is only after October. Is there a possible work around for this problem?